# call an instance method from an interface class

Tags: python, design-patterns, interface, stack

I am looking for a way to call an instance method from an other class and I wondered if/how I could could do the following

#### goal and context

The class I am writing is a **data formater** whose `__rshift__` method should be able to adapt the format of a data `batch` to **many data base clients** without the user needing to change the method used. Here is how I would like the `>>` method to be called

```py
batch  = SomeExtractor(config).extract("some")
db_client = InfluxDBClient()
# this would be awesome
DataFormater(batch)>>db_client.write_points
```

#### the DataFormater

```py
class DataFormater(object): 
  def __init__(self, batch: Batch): 
    self.batch = batch

  @abstractmethod
  def __rshift__(self, db): 
    db_client = some_way_to_get_the_called_client(db)
    method = some_way_to_get_the_method(db)

    if method == InfluxDBClient.write_points:
      db_client.write_points({"measurement": self.batch.origin, 
                "time" : self.batch.date, 
                "tags": dict(zip(self.batch.dimensions_names, row["dimensions"])),
                "fields": dict(zip(self.batch.metrics_names, row["values"])}
                for row in self.batch.rows))
```

Googling my problem, added `stack = inspect.stack(db)` in the `__rshift__` method and got the following but I am not sure how to use it

```
frame = <frame at 0x7f6c2a1515c0, file '/usr/src/collector/collector.py', line 95, code __rshift__>
context = <bound method InfluxDBClient.write_points of <collector.InfluxDBClient object at 0x7f6c2a131510>>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You are already passing `db_client.write_points` to `__rshift__` method here: `DataFormater(batch)>>db_client.write_points`.

Comment: yeah but how can I check that its instance is an `InfluxDBClient` and how to use this instance to write data?

Comment: `type(db_client.write_points.__self__) == InfluxDBClient`

Comment: `db_client.write_points.__self__` gives you an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elegant solution proposed by @sanyash using `__self__`:

```
class DataFormater(object): 
  def __init__(self, batch: Batch): 
    self.batch = batch

  @abstractmethod
  def __rshift__(self, db_method): 
    if type(db_method.__self__) == InfluxDBClient: 
      db_method( ({"measurement": self.batch.origin,
        "time" : self.batch.date, 
        "tags": dict(zip(self.batch.dimensions_names, row["dimensions"])),
        "fields": dict(zip(self.batch.metrics_names, row["values"]))}) for row in self.batch.rows )
```